# Highlighting with mark.js working for only 1-3 letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) on a page, but it isn't working correctly. So I setup a very basic page, and pulled all of the code from [this jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/), however it will only highlight certain 1-3 letters at a time, depending on whatever I put in. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong exactly? My page is [located here](http://airs.okstate.edu/okcorral/markjs/).

Code:

```
$(function() {

      // the input field
      var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
        // clear button
        $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
        // prev button
        $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
        // next button
        $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
        // the context where to search
        $content = $(".content"),
        // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
        $results,
        // the class that will be appended to the current
        // focused element
        currentClass = "current",
        // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
        offsetTop = 50,
        // the current index of the focused element
        currentIndex = 0;

      /**
       * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
       */
      function jumpTo() {
        if ($results.length) {
          var position,
            $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
          $results.removeClass(currentClass);
          if ($current.length) {
            $current.addClass(currentClass);
            position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
            window.scrollTo(0, position);
          }
        }
      }

      /**
       * Searches for the entered keyword in the
       * specified context on input
       */
      $input.on("input", function() {
        var searchVal = this.value;
        $content.unmark({
          done: function() {
            $content.mark(searchVal, {
              separateWordSearch: true,
              done: function() {
                $results = $content.find("mark");
                currentIndex = 0;
                jumpTo();
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });

      /**
       * Clears the search
       */
      $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
        $content.unmark();
        $input.val("").focus();
      });

      /**
       * Next and previous search jump to
       */
      $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
        if ($results.length) {
          currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
          if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
          }
          if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
          }
          jumpTo();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: I cannot explain why, but the code works on another site. I copied your whole source from http://airs.okstate.edu/okcorral/markjs/ and even linked to your hosted `jquery` and `jquery.mark` files. And it works like it should....

Comment: Wow, really? That's is very odd. Hmmm

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being an encoding issue. Adding:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

resolved the problem.